# jk_mod not working without any error

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-jk

I tried to connect Apache2 and Tomcat via jk_mod, but I can't get it to work. When I open a page which is supposed to be redirected to an application, I fall on my "normal" Apache HTTP 404 page. The thing is that everything seems to be correctly configurated since I don't see any error on any log (Apache is fine, jk_mod is fine and Tomcat is fine too)... And I know that everything is loaded because if I change my JkMount line then I have an error in mod_jk.log.

Here is a part of my VirtualHost :

```
NameVirtualHost  *:443

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName xx
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews -ExecCGI
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Java
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName xx
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews -ExecCGI
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

    SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile xx
        SSLCertificateKeyFile xx
    SSLCACertificateFile xx

    JkMount /LaunchMyCraft/* ajp13_worker
</VirtualHost>
```

And here is the loaded workers file :

```
workers.tomcat_home=/usr/share/tomcat7
workers.java_home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre

ps=/

worker.list=ajp13_worker
worker.ajp13_worker.port=8009
worker.ajp13_worker.host=localhost
worker.ajp13_worker.type=ajp13

worker.ajp13_worker.lbfactor=1


worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=ajp13_worker
```

Could you help me ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention what URL you are accessing when you get a 404, but if you are accessing `http://xx/LaunchMyCraft` (without the trailing slash), then this is expected since your JkMount directive maps to `/LaunchMyCraft/*` (with the trailing slash).

To fix this, change your JkMount mapping to `/LaunchMyCraft*` (no trailing slash).

Comment: Thanks for the reply it fixed it, however now I have a "Service Temporarly Unavailable" webpage... I will watch for the logs as soon as I return in front of my computer, what could be the cause of this ?

Comment: It can be many things, would need more details. Probably better to ask a new question.